# Exporting data to an excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vb6, export-to-excel, vba

Question 1: Data to be exported to Excel is prepared using a two dimensional array object in my vb.net code. When tried to assign this array object to the ExcelRange.Value or .Value2 properties, it works fine except when the text length of any cell value to be exported exceeds 8203 (it throws an exception with msg “Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC”)

Question 2: Whereas, using the excelrange.FormulaArray property, error occurs with message “Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class”. But it works fine in vb6 using string array.
What is the reason ?
Below is the detailed error when I use excelrange.FormulaArray property

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
ErrorCode=-2146827284
HelpLink="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033\XLMAIN11.CHM"
Message="Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class"
Source="Microsoft Office Excel"
StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Excel.Range.set_FormulaArray(Object )
   at globalmodule.modglobconstant.ExportMsfgToExcel(AxMSFlexGrid& Msfg1, Boolean& flg, String FileName1)
InnerException:
```

Any other alternative methods of exporting to excel/solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [Excel 2010 Performance: Performance and Limit Improvements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700514%28v=office.14%29.aspx#Office2007excelPerf_BigGridIncreasedLimitsExcel) the limit to a cell formula is 8000 characters. However further testing shows that a string of 32767 characters is accepted by Excel 2007 (I haven't a copy of 2010 to hand).
2. If you're transferring from a table, normally you would use `.Value` or `.Formula`, `FormulaArray` is for the special case where one formula is applied to a range of cells.

In the test case submitted, you were trying to assign a VB array to Range.Value. Changing this to assign a single member of the array worked.

Comment: I have created a simple code in the excel macro which demonstrates the error i am getting.Download the file here [link](http://incometaxsoft.com/pdf/test1.xlsm)  Here i have wriiten simple excel macro with A10 cell updating values from A1. Since A1 contains a length text(more than 8000 characters) so its not updating in A10

Comment: In macro i have written two cases.one for error case and another for normal case.you can comment the line and see the error.